GCP Load Balancer and any unmatched hosts
I am trying to set up a GCP Load Balancer for my Cloud Run instances. As I've understood, I have to define a Backend, a Routing Rule and an A-Record for each of my cloud run. I would like to redirect all unmatched to my website, so I switched to the "Advanced host and path rule", in the Default one I set "Redirect the client to different host/path", add my full domain (https://example.com) in the "Host redirect" field and enabled HTTPS.
When navigating to the IP of my balancer "https://<balancer_ip>" I expected to be redirected to my home page, but I get ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH.
Am I right? I am missing something?

It ended up, that the IT did not set up correctly the DNS. Once fixed the A-Record(s), it worked.

You have to keep in mind that loadbalancer rules the order matters.
So if you are trying to have a default route based on host or path, you proprably must put this configuration in the end of the others.

Well, on the GCP it is not possible to move the default one, so I suppose google is handling it properly.
